# I want to sell fixed amount of product to client . How to manage concurrancy in spring jpa?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, concurrency, transactions

In Spring Boot with spring data jpa.

I have a use case
 where I want to sell n number of product and got the request for the n+1 product at a time. so how can I ensure that I should sell only n product an do fail all another request.

> Suppose I have 10 quantity for any product id 1.  And got 11 requests
>   at the same time for that particular product. How I can ensure that
>   system sell only 10 product and fail the last request because of out
>   of stock.
>
> All the request can execute at the same time.

I am using MySql.

if I am using @version it fails all others transaction except 1st one.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
public class ProductStockTable {

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;

    private Long productId;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    private Long currentStock;

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Long getCurrentStock() {
        return currentStock;
    }

    public void setCurrentStock(Long currentStock) {
        this.currentStock = currentStock;
    }
}

    @Transactional
public boolean checkStock(Long productId, Integer stock) {

        ProductStockTable ps = stockRepo.findById(productId);
        if (ps.getCurrentStock() > stock) {
            ps.setCurrentStock(ps.getCurrentStock()-stock);
            stockRepo.save(ps);
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

If I make MySql constraint `not negative` for currentStock, its also not working.

Is there any possible way to achieve this in Spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

Call to your checkstock function right before the process is completed? Once in the beginning, and once at the end, and directly after update the database and change the stock.

Another option could be when you have a request get sent - update that stock before finalization (So that way its locked out while its in someones cart). Put a timer on the cart so after 5 minutes its automatically restocked (I prefer option 1, updating the database usually puts a temporary lock that will stop select statement until the update is complete)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `LockMode`.

One solution would be to use `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` when you read the row from your `ProductStockTable` entity.  This mode will prevent all other reads from happening, basically think of it as an exclusive lock on that row until you're done with it.  Then once the lock is released, the next contender can lock it and so on.

This will have some performance impact on rows that are accessed frequently in a concurrent pattern, but its a great starting point to solve your problem until you can re-evaluate other alternatives.